# Maximum of a concave function using directional derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I have a question regarding this fact:

> "*Recall that a concave function $u:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ attains its maximum at a point $x$ if and only if its directional derivative $u'(x;d)$ at point $x$ in any direction $d \in X-\{x\}$ is non-positive.*"

where $X$ is a non-empty, compact and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for some $n \in \mathbb{N}^\ast$).

For simplicity, consider the case where $n = 1$ and $u: [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is affine and strictly increasing ($a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $0 < a < b$).

First question: Can we talk about directional derivative at points $a$ and $b$ (I think that this notion is defined only when the domain of $u$ is open) ?
I guess that we have two options: $(1)$ take the right directional derivative for $a$ and the left directional derivative for $b$, or $(2)$ extend $u$ to another function $U: O \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto u(x)$, where $O$ is open and define the directional derivatives of $a$ and $b$ using $U$. In general, do we use one of this option or something different ?

Second question: In that case, $u$ attains its maximum at $b$, but considering the two previous options: $(1)$ I don't think that the directional derivative $u'(b,d)$ at point $b$ in any direction $d \in [a,b[$ is non-positive and $(2)$ I don't even have the feeling that it is a good idea to proceed like this, because I think that the directional derivatives at points $a$ and $b$ will depend on $U$...
Could you tell me where I'm wrong/missing something ?

Thank you for you help !

Comment: Perhaps it is the one sided directional derivative? For example, $x \mapsto |x|$ is convex everywhere but does not have a two sided directional derivative at $x=0$. Also, the function $x \mapsto \sqrt{1-x^2}$ is convex on $[-1,1]$ but does not have a (conventional) one sided directional derivative at $\pm 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I think in terms of convex functions, take the negative of my examples.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for you answer. The problem is that I still don't really get how can I use the proposition to solve my second problem...

Answer (score 1):

The (one sided) directional derivative is defined as (notations differ)
$u'(x,d) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} {u(x+td)-u(x) \over t}$.

It is straightforward to show (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) for some discussion) that for a concave function $f$ defined on an interval the quantity $R(t_1,t_2) = {f(t_1)-f(t_2) \over t_1-t_2}$ (with $t_1 \neq t_2$, of course) is symmetric in $t_1,t_2$ and non increasing in $t_1$ for a fixed $t_2$.

In particular, $u'(x,d) = \sup_{t >0} {u(x+td)-u(x) \over t}$ is well defined (it may be $+\infty$) for any direction $d \in X \setminus \{x\}$.

In your example, $u$ is affine so $u(x) = v+tg$ for some $x,w$ and the
directional derivative is given by

1. $u'(x,d) = gd$ for $x \in (a,b)$ and any $d$
2. $u'(a,d) = gd$ for any $d \ge 0$
3. $u'(b,d) = gd$ for any $d \le 0$